# sed misbehaving?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following command:

```
$ xlscat -i $file
```

and I get:

```
Excel File Name.xslx - 01:  [ Sheet #1      ] 34 Cols,    433 Rows
Excel File Name.xlsx - 02:  [ Sheet Number2 ] 23 Cols,     32 Rows
Excel File Name.xlsx - 03:  [ Foo Factor!   ] 14 Cols,    123 Rows
```

I want just the sheet name, so i do this:

```
$ xlscat -i $file 2>&1 | sed -e 's/.*\[  *\(.*\)  *\].*/\1/' | while read file
> do
>    echo "File: '$file'"
> done
```

And get this:

```
File: 'Sheet #1'
File: 'Sheet Number2'
File: 'Foo Factor!'
```

Great! Everything works beautifully. As you can see with the single quotes, I've removed the extra spaces at the end of the file name. Now convert all remaining spaces to underscores:

```
$ xlscat -i $file 2>&1 | sed -e 's/.*\[  *\(.*\)  *\].*/\1/' | sed -e 's/ /_/g' |  while read file
> do
>    echo "File: '$file'"
> done
```

Now I get this:

```
File: 'Sheet_#1_____'
File: 'Sheet_Number2'
File: 'Foo_Factor!__'
```

Huh? The first one didn't show any trailing blanks, but the second one seems to be appending  underscores on the end of the file. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `sed` command is not stripping the trailing whitespace, `read` is.  Check your expression:

```
 sed -e 's/.*\[  *\(.*\)  *\].*/\1/'
```

It matches:

1. anything
2. a bracket
3. 1 or more spaces
4. anything, captured
5. 1 or more spaces
6. a right bracket
7. anything

The regular expressions are greedy, meaning that they match as much as possible, and the earlier expressions will match before later ones do.  So for example, the regular expression `(.*)(.*)` matches anything in two capturing groups, but there are any number of ways the data could be split between the two groups.  So the regex implementation has to choose, and it will put as much as possible in the first, and nothing in the second.

Since you need to match filenames with spaces in them, you can't match "anything except a space";  your best bet is to trim the trailing whitespace as a separate step.  Try this sed command instead:

```
sed -e 's/.*\[  *\(.*\)  *\].*/\1/' -e 's/ *$//'
```

Comment: Okay, I see the problem now. My "Match Anything" capture is being greedy and matching the spaces on the end except for the one right before closing square bracket. You're right, the `read` is stripping the spaces. I guess I'll have to follow what [P.T.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/960524/p-t) said and strip out the rest in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

I think the `read file` is trimming the trailing whitespace for you.  Try putting the

```
sed -e 's/ /_/g'
```

inside the while loop ... like:

```
echo "File: $(echo $file | sed -e 's/ /_/g')"
```

Comment: It sure does trim spaces and turns sequences of whitespaces into a single space, which can be prevented by turning it to `IFS= read file` if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't answer my question: Why does the first example show the trailing spaces as being removed, but the second example, it appears that the second `sed` command actually _sees_ the previously removed spaces. Originally, it was a single `sed` command with two `-e` parameters, but after seeing the result, I figured that the two substitutions might be happening in parallel. However, the pip should have fixed that. I must be missing something obvious. What is it?

Comment: @DavidW. the first example does not show that `sed` removed the trailing spaces (see evil otto's answer for more details on why sed is, in fact, matching the whitespace).  The first example just shows that the whitespace was gone by the time `echo` ran.  (Its the `read` eating the whitespace.)  In the second example the whitespace is replaced with underscores before the `read` runs, so there is no whitespace for `read` to eat.

Comment: The first `sed` command was never stripping trailing spaces, `read` was doing that (see @evil otto's answer). In the second version, the trailing spaces were converted to "_" before read saw them, so they were never stripped.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be `echo` that's stripping the trailing spaces?  Although it does seem like they should show up inside the quotes.  Anyway, try this:

```
sed -e 's/.*\[ *\([^] ]\+\( \+[^] ]\+\)*\).*/\1/'
```

Each word of the sheet name is matched by `[^] ]\+` (i.e., one or more of any characters other than space or `]`).  When the final word of the name has been matched, the second `.*` consumes the rest of the line.  There's no need to match the closing `]`, so the trailing spaces don't have to be included in the match.

I'm not a `sed` user, but this regex works correctly in RegexBuddy when I specify the GNU-BRE flavor, so it should work in `sed`.